# How to display any html content in thick box using joomla 1.5 and mootools 1.1

Tags: mootools, joomla1.5, thickbox

I am developing one site using joomla 1.5 and mootools 1.1 for js framework,

in that i need to display some HTML content to be displayed in thick box.

I have tried a lot, but its not working for me not even giving an error.

Please let me know if have any solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Are you starting from scratch? Do you have the content being displayed and you're moving to thickbox? And you want to display it on a click, or on a load? Hard to answer without more information.

Comment: i want to  display it on click of link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has Squeezebox built in, and you can use it to show an iFrame with any HTML you want. Squeezebox uses MooTools which is also built into Joomla. JQuery works with Joomla but sometimes can cause conflicts. See [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2299973/Joomla-v-15-Squeezebox-in-your-Joomla-Website) for Squeezebox guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is intended to be used in conjunction with jQuery. [Smoothbox](http://gueschla.com/labs/smoothbox/), however, is a port to MooTools. I suggest you add the Smoothbox files to your project and look over [the demo code](http://gueschla.com/labs/smoothbox/).